# Splitting a String into Command Line Arguments

Tags: shell, fish

I am trying to split a sting from the command-line history of the user into command line arguments. For instance, I want to split

```
program argument escaped\ argument.txt -o 'another escaped.output'
```

into

```
$v[1]: program
$v[2]: argument
$v[3]: escaped argument.txt
$v[4]: -o
$v[5]: another escaped.output
```

I have tried every single possible solution that I could, but as fish quotes the variables automatically, none of my solutions worked.

Thanks!

Comment: You want to store into an `bash` array?

Comment: @Inian into a fish (https://fishshell.com/) array.

Comment: "fish quotes the variables automatically" - well, no. It just doesn't split it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, there's no clean way to do this in fish.

The best I could come up with is quite a hack:

```
set s "program argument escaped\ argument.txt -o 'another escaped.output'"
set oldcmd (commandline)
commandline -r -- $s
set v (commandline -o)
commandline -r -- $oldcmd
printf '%s\n' $v
```

This abuses fish's commandline buffer, which does properly tokenize its contents.

Answer (score 4):

This is where you need `eval`.

```
$ set s "program argument escaped\ argument.txt -o 'another escaped.output'"
$ eval set v $s
$ printf "%s\n" $v
program
argument
escaped argument.txt
-o
another escaped.output
```

Comment: Note that this _will_ run any command substitutions and similar in the argument, and there's no easy way around it.